# PHP and HTML commenting system

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to build a comment system

this is my code

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <style>
            .back_glob{width: 350px}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function(){
                $( ".tombol_login" ).click(function() {
                    var txt = $("[name=comment]").val();
                        $("#comment").submit();


                })});
        </script>


        <style> 
            .back_glob{width: 450px}
        </style>

    </head>


    <body>
        <div class = "back_glob">
                    <div class="tableC">
                        <a href="contetmenu.php"><img src="img\back.png" alt="back" height="42" width="42"></a>
                                    <div class ="back_header">
                                        <h4>comment</h4>
                                    </div>
                    <div class= "table">
                        <form id="comment" name="comment" action="contet2.php" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">comment</div> 
                                <div class="col">:</div>
                                <div class="col"><textarea name="comment" rows ="10" cols="40"></textarea></div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="tom">
                                     <button type="button" class="tombol_login">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>




<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "databaseform";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

session_start();
        $page = 2;

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host =$servername ; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $query = "SELECT form.Username, comment.Comment, comment.time FROM
             form, comment WHERE
             form.pkey=comment.pkey AND
             comment.page=$page
             ORDER BY comment.time DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        $hasil = $result->fetchAll();

    $Comment = $_POST['comment'];


 try
    {


     //        injec
        $query = "INSERT INTO comment (pkey,Comment,time,page)
                VALUES (:Username,:Comment,NOW(),:page)";
        $sql = $conn->prepare($query) ;
        $sql->BindValue(':Username',reset($_SESSION['txt_login']));
        $sql->BindValue(':Comment',$Comment);
        $sql->BindValue(':page',$page);
        $sql->execute();


    $query = "SELECT form.Username, comment.Comment, comment.time FROM
             form, comment WHERE
             form.pkey=comment.pkey AND
             comment.page=$page
             ORDER BY comment.time DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        $hasil = $result->fetchAll();



        echo '<div class="back_glob">';
                echo '<div class = "table">';
                    echo '<div class = "tableC">';
                    echo '</div>';
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $query . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }


        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($hasil);$i++)
                    {
                    echo'<div class="row">';
                        echo '<div class="col2">'.$result[$i]['Username'].'</div>';
                        echo '<div class="col2">'.$result[$i]['Comment'].'</div>';
                        echo '<div class="col2">'.$result[$i]['time'].'</div>';
                    echo'</div>';
                    }

?>
```

but the php part won't recognize the `$_POST['comment']` before the submit button , i can't show the previous comment unless I click the submit button.

Is there any solution to correct this ??

Answer (score 0):

I am really confused about your way of asking a question. I think you should have to read this tutorial of [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/building-real-time-commenting-system/). So you can better understand of code and comment system.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Next time i will.

Comment: what i'm trying to say is that when I go to the comment page , I expect to see the other comment that was submitted before I went to the page atm . In my code I made a variable called "comment" inside a form with a post method , so the php will recognize the comment as  "$_POST['comment']" . But in order to do so i have to click the submit button , otherwise "$_POST['comment']" will not be created hence the php does not recognize any comment input . What i'm asking is  there a way around it ? Hope this clarify my question.